# Should I use "test" or "[" "]" in POSIX shell?

Tags: shell, posix, sh

I believe both of the following code snippets are valid in POSIX compliant shell:

*Option 1:*

```
if [ "$var" = "dude" ]
then
  echo "Dude, your var equals dude."
fi
```

*Option 2:*

```
if test "$var" = "dude"
then
  echo "Dude, your var equals dude."
fi
```

Which syntax is preferred and why? Is there a reason to use one over the other in certain situations?

Comment: Yes, they're both valid. No, there's not a particular reason to prefer one over the other -- it's a stylistic choice.

Comment: `test` will probably result in a process fork and thus be less efficient.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, on a shell where `test` isn't a builtin, then it'll also be using an external `/usr/bin/[` -- look for it, your operating system *does* ship that as an external binary (often, a hardlink to the same inode as `/usr/bin/test`, which looks at its `argv[0]` to see how it was called and decide whether to discard a trailing `]` from its argument list).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: ok, many thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The pedant in me can't help but think that the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no functional difference, making this a purely stylistic choice with no widely accepted guidelines. [The bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest) has an extended section on classic (POSIX-compliant) `test`, with a great deal of attention to best practices and pitfalls, and takes no position on which to prefer.

Moreover, [the POSIX specification for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) -- while it *does* mark a great deal of functionality obsolescent<sup>1</sup> -- specifies neither form as preferred over the other.

That said, one advantage to `test` is that it's less conducive to folks bringing in expectations from other languages which result in broken or buggy code. For instance, it's a common error to write `[$foo=1]` rather than the correct `[ "$foo" = 1 ]`, but folks aren't widely seen to write `test$foo=1`: It's more visually obvious that `test "$foo" = 1` is following the same parsing rules as other shell commands, and thus requires the same care regarding quoting and whitespace.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Such as `-a`, `-o`, `(` and `)`, and any usage with more than four arguments (excluding the trailing `]` on an instance started under the name `[`).

Comment: POSIX shell does not consider `-a` or `-o` to be obsolescent. [**POSIX Programmer's Manual (test)**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128) I believe the argument against their use is *lack of clairity* after Bash introduced `-a` (*true if file exists*). But POSIX test makes no mention of `&&` or `||`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ...if you click on `[OB XSI]` anywhere given in that spec -- to which you linked -- it opens the following, which explains those codes (and thus that `OB` means obsolescent): http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html. To quote from there: "The functionality described may be removed in a future version of this volume of POSIX.1-2008. Strictly Conforming POSIX Applications and Strictly Conforming XSI Applications shall not use obsolescent features."

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ...and there are good reasons for that: In the more-than-four-argument cases with `-a` and `-o`, there are ambiguities where the `"x$foo"` idiom can be necessary to disambiguate interpretation between values and test syntax (particularly when that set of values can include `(` or `)`).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ...to provide a specific case which explains *why* these extensions are better dead than alive, consider `[ '(' = ')' ]` -- under XSI rules this checks whether `=` is a non-empty string and must return true; under non-XSI rules, it checks whether the strings `(` and `)` match each other and must return false. Hence, `[ "x$foo" = "x$bar" ]` being necessary to disambiguate. I believe we can both agree that this is a serious bug in the XSI-extended spec.

Comment: I agree with all points, my concern for the most part was in the use of *obsolescent* which has the primary meaning (according to [**Websters**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolescent) ) of *no longer useful* which is indeed not the case.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, noted. I'm holding to that terminology only because it's what the POSIX specification itself uses in the context at hand.

Comment: I don't think the clarity of `test` is a "minor" advantage.  I would say it far outweighs the single char saved by using `[`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, fair point that I'm injecting rather overmuch judgment; redacted the word.

Comment: I would advise a *strong* preference for `test`, given the number of questions on SO that mistake `[` and `]` for grouping operators.

Comment: I'm happy to upvote comments effectively advocating a preference., such that they're visible to folks viewing the question who don't expand comments. That said, barring a preference documented in a consensus-driven source (POSIX spec or a well-maintained community wiki such as the Wooledge or bash-hackers ones), I'm leaning towards keeping the answer itself neutral.

Comment: Moreover, `--`, e.g. `[ --help`.

Comment: @FrankHB, pardon? `[ --help` correctly fails with something along the lines of `[: missing ]` in every implementation I'm aware of (whereas `test --help` correctly exits with a truthy status and no output, having tested `--help` and determined it to be a non-empty string). Which is to say: The behaviors are _different_, but they're both _correct_. (Though it would also be defensible for `[ --help` to write a help message when there's no following `]`; since it's not a syntactically valid usage, it's fair game for extensions in a way that `test --help` isn't).

Comment: @FrankHB, ...`test`, unlike almost all other POSIX-specified commands, looks at total argument count in determining how to parse a value. If you have `[ <anything> = <anything> ]`, for example, the `<anything>`s won't be evaluated at all in a POSIX-standard implementation, _except_ for purposes of determining whether they're identical. It's only after you have more than three arguments (excluding `[` and `]`, and a legal 3-arg case preceded by a `!`) that determining what's a value and what's an operator gets sticky, which is why POSIX has marked all those usage modes obsolescent.

Comment: @FrankHB, ...so, for `test --help`, the single-argument rule applies: For *all* possible single-argument values, the only thing a `test` implementation can legally do is check whether it's an empty string, return a falsey value if it is indeed empty, and return a truthy value otherwise. No other behavior is allowed by the POSIX spec, no exceptions.

Comment: @Charles Duffy This is shell-specific. Ensure that `[` is not a shell builtin (e.g. see the result of `type [`), or alternatively, try `\`which [\` --help`, and there comes the difference (at least GNU's implementation has an explicit NOTE specific to this issue in the output). Note the [POSIX requirement](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html): The _test_ utility shall not recognize the "--" argument ... This effectively allows the difference, because the italic _test_ is a _utility name_, so this rule does not apply to `[`.

Comment: @FrankHB, once again, `[ --help` is invalid syntax, so implementations are free to change its meaning however they like. It's treating `[ --help ]` differently that would be a problem.

Comment: The POSIX requirement you quote is referring to the precise string `--` on its own, as used in utility syntax guideline #10 (see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html); it's not making reference to longer arguments that start with `--` as a prefix.