# What is `test ( foo )` / `[ ( foo )` in Bash?

Tags: bash, syntax-error

The *Bash Reference Manual* mentions the following about the [`test` / `[` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-test):

> **1 argument**
>
> The expression is true if, and only if, the argument is not null.

So far so good:

```
$ test "foo"
$ echo $?
0

$ test foo
$ echo $?
0

$ test ""
$ echo $?
1

$ SET_VARIABLE="hello"
$ test $SET_VARIABLE
$ echo $?
0

$ unset UNSET_VARIABLE
$ test $UNSET_VARIABLE
$ echo $?
1

$ NULL_VARIABLE=
$ test $NULL_VARIABLE
$ echo $?
1
```

But then, the manual mentions the following for three arguments:

> **3 arguments**
>
> ...
>
> If the first argument is exactly ‘(’ and the third argument is exactly ‘)’, the result is the one-argument test of the second argument.

I cannot find any working example for this three-argument case; any attempt results in a syntax error:

```
$ test ( "foo" )
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"foo"'
$ echo $?
2

$ test ( foo )
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `foo'
$ echo $?
2

$ test ( "" )
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `""'
$ echo $?
2
```

The same syntax error happens for the corresponding 4-argument case: `test ( -d /boot )` fails with a syntax error, while the 2-argument expression `test -d /boot` works fine.

My `bash` version is `5.1.4(1)-release`, and `man bash` states *GNU Bash 5.1* at the end, and the manpage mentions the syntax under question.

**What are working examples for `test`'s parantheses syntax, and for what can this syntax be used for?**

Comment: `man bash` is a huge documentation but somewhere it explains the syntax and arguments of `test` and `[`.

Comment: See `help test` , At the bottom where it says `Exit Status:`  Also running `( foo )` alone evaluates to false, with an exit status of `127` except or course if you have an executable named `foo` within your `PATH`

Comment: man bash also explains `[ ... ]` is simply an alias for `test` on shells where it is a builtin. See, e.g. [Should I use "test" or "\[" "\]" in POSIX shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38001248/3422102) and [POSIX test](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)

Comment: Parentheses are special characters in shell syntax; you must quote or escape them to pass them in arguments. This is one of the advantages of `[[ ]]` conditional expressions over `test` / `[ ]` -- the `[[ ]]` expression isn't a command, and isn't subject to normal command parsing, so it uses parentheses, comparisons with `<` and `>`, conjunctions with `||` and `&&` etc without them needing to be quoted or escaped (and unlike `test`, its syntax is unambiguous, so it's safer for anything complex).

Comment: Parentheses have special meaning to bash. You have to escape them: `test \( whatever \) `. BTW, the internal bash commands `test` and `[` are just internal reimplementations   of the external commands of the same name (with tiny extensions, relating to testing for equality), and I suggest that use `man test` for learning about these commands.  Different to `[`, `[[` is not a command, but a syntacting construct in bash, and different rules about quoting apply inside `[[ ... ]]`, and  I suggest that you use that construct from within bash, instead of relying on the `[` command.

Comment: @axiac, have you actually read my question or used `man bash`? Because the manpage does not explain it, hence the question.

Comment: The manual says _"If the first argument is exactly ‘(’"_. This means that `(` must not be evaluated by Bash but passed as argument to `test`. This happens when `(` is quoted or escaped. Use `test '(' "foo" ')'` or `test \( "foo" \)`, otherwise the parentheses are interpreted by Bash (that triggers the error) and `test` is not executed and does not have any chance to check its number of arguments. All these are described in the manual but, as I said, it is huge and one have to read a lot of it to understand how it works.

Answer (score 5):

You are right about the three-arguments usage of `test`, but `(`, `)` are reserved words in bash, that indicate to run the command provided inside, in a sub-shell context. You need to deprive of its special meaning, when trying to use along with `test`

```bash
$ touch foo
$ test \( -f foo \)
$ echo $?
0
```

If you are using bash and not worried about portability, prefer `[[` over the legacy `[` built-in. More insights on the difference between is well written at [BashFAQ/031 - What is the difference between `test`, `\[` and `\[\[` ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: thank you. Are there any situations where adding these parentheses to `test` makes sense? I cannot identify any example where they clarify, disambiguate, or influence precedence.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't use `test` at all, the syntax is bad, outdated and archaic. I would use the cleaner syntax with `[` and if portability is not an issue, definitely with bash's `[[`.

Answer (score 3):

> If the first argument is exactly ‘(’ and the third argument is exactly ‘)’, the result is the one-argument test of the second argument.

```bash
$ test "(" "foo" ")"
$ echo $?
0

$ test "(" "" ")"
$ echo $?
1
```

so indeed the exit code matches that which would result if only the second argument was used as argument.

```bash
$ test "foo"
$ echo $?
0

$ test ""
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: thank you. Are there any situations where adding these parentheses to `test` makes sense? I cannot identify any example where they clarify, disambiguate, or influence precedence.

Comment: @Abdull I don't see why someone would want to do that. Are you trying to solve a specific problem, or is it just a curiosity?

Comment: out of curiosity, considering the verbosity and complexity the `test` parentheses bring to the documentation, yet effectively boil down to a pointless feature, I initially thought I missed a nifty trick I wanted to learn more about.

Comment: @Abdull if there was a use case it's certainly not documented properly!